# Error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float

Tags: java, double, equation, area

I've been running this code and keep receiving errors, not sure why. Double to float?
Keep receiving message "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float ." Is there any issue with conversions how to the conversion so there is no error
This is part of a larger code.

```
  public static float getAreaOfPentagon(float l) {
  float area = Math.sqrt(5 * (5 + 2 * (Math.sqrt(5))) * l * l) / 4;
  return area;
}
```

Comment: I would have made the type of the method to be double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast.  Or declare `area` as `double`.

```
float area = (float)(Math.sqrt(5 * (5 + 2 *
   (Math.sqrt(5))) * l * l) / 4);
```

or

```
double area = Math.sqrt(5 * (5 + 2 *
   (Math.sqrt(5))) * l * l) / 4;
```

Aside: you are mixing integers and floating point in the same equation.  Often this leads to disaster.  It's probably better to use double literals.

```
double area = Math.sqrt(5.0 * (5.0 + 2.0 *
   (Math.sqrt(5.0))) * l * l) / 4.0;
```